# Batch file moving files with spaces in their name.

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, names

My hope is that some can help me out I've spent the last few days searching Google for answers and not getting anywhere. I have a two part code fist pulls everything out of sub-folders and then the second part moves those files by type into other folders located else where. I can get the code to work in a test set up, but it wont on the files I'm trying to move. I think it has to do with the names of the files having spaces in them, but I am not sure. Here are the codes. thanks guys!

Part one

```
FOR /R C:\Users\Laptop02\Desktop\Folder 1 Test  %%i IN (*.*) DO MOVE %%i C:\Users\Laptop02\Desktop\Folder 1 Test
```

Second Part

```
@echooff
set media=C:\Users\Laptop02\Desktop\Foder 2 Test
set jpg=C:\Users\Laptop02\Desktop\Foder 2 Test\mediadata
set xml=C:\Users\Laptop02\Desktop\Foder 2 Test\mediadata

move %dlDir%*.avi %media%
move %dlDir%*/*.avi %meia%
move %dlDir%*.mp4 %media%
move %dlDir%*/*.mp4 %media%
move %dlDir%*.mkv %media%
move %dlDir%*/*.mkv %media%
move %dlDir%*.jpg %jpg%
move %dlDir%**.xml %xml%
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the move command is good and the method above works, it should be faster copying or moving many files using the following `robocopy` command with multi-thread support:

```
@echo off
set "source=C:\Users\Laptop02\Desktop\Folder 1 Test"
set "media=C:\Users\Laptop02\Desktop\Foder 2 Test"
set "jpg=C:\Users\Laptop02\Desktop\Foder 2 Test\mediadata"
set "xml=C:\Users\Laptop02\Desktop\Foder 2 Test\mediadata"
robocopy /s /mov /mt "%source%" "%media%" *.avi
robocopy /s /mov /mt "%source%" "%media%" *.mp4
robocopy /s /mov /mt "%source%" "%media%" *.mkv
robocopy /s /mov /mt "%source%" "%jpg%" *.jpg
robocopy /s /mov /mt "%source%" "%xml%" *.xml
pause
```

Alternatively, it would also be faster to move the files only once:

```
@echo off
set "source=C:\Users\Laptop02\Desktop\Folder 1 Test"
set "media=C:\Users\Laptop02\Desktop\Foder 2 Test"
set "jpg=C:\Users\Laptop02\Desktop\Foder 2 Test\mediadata"
set "xml=C:\Users\Laptop02\Desktop\Foder 2 Test\mediadata"

cd "%source%"
for /r "%~dp0" %%A in (*) do (
    if "%%~xA"==".avi" move "%%~A" "%media%\"
    if "%%~xA"==".mp4" move "%%~A" "%media%\"
    if "%%~xA"==".mkv" move "%%~A" "%media%\"
    if "%%~xA"==".jpg" move "%%~A" "%jpg%\"
    if "%%~xA"==".xml" move "%%~A" "%xml%\"
)
pause
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to place quotes around files that might have spaces in the name, e.g.

```
move "%dlDir%*.avi" "%media%"
```

**UPDATE**

For the `for` portion, add

```
"delims="
```

like this:

```
FOR /F "delims=" IN (dir /b /s "C:\Users\Laptop02\Desktop\Folder 1 Test")
```

Comment: Still need help with the first part though. Still wont pull files with spaces in there names out of sub-folders.

Comment: @IdeaBak: Did you quote your variable `DO MOVE "%%i"`?

Comment: Does your Part 1 look like this: `FOR /R "C:\Users\Laptop02\Desktop\Folder 1 Test"  %%i IN (*.*) DO MOVE "%%i" "C:\Users\Laptop02\Desktop\Folder 1 Test"` ?  Anytime you are using a literal string containing spaces, the spaces need to be encapsulated by using surrounding quotations.

Comment: @David it did not, how ever changing it to what you have has not worked either. I thank you for your help though.

Comment: @IdeaBak is it displaying any error messages when running the batch script?  That can usually narrow the search for the issue.  Are there any other special characters in the filenames? `"()!&`

Comment: It looks as though nothing happens, a quick fast then nothing.

Comment: Are you running the script from an already open cmd prompt?  If not the script will immediately close when an error occurs and if a `pause` is not specified at the end of the script.  Also, I tested my snippet and it seems to work just fine on filenames containing spaces.

Comment: No I running them as .Bat files because I use a scheduler to make the moves every morning while I am at work.

Comment: @IdeaBak: Updated my answer.  You need to add something to the for command.

Comment: @IdeaBak  A good method for testing bat files when developing them is to open a cmd console and run the bat file within the console, that way all the errors are printed out to the screen of the console.

Comment: @EricJ.  Unfortunately, I do not believe the `delims` option is supported by the `/r` recursive mode.  The default for the recursive mode is to place then entire file path into the variable specified.
See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx  `ParsingKeywords` is only supported for the `/f` mode.

Comment: @DavidRuhmann: You can ditch /r and instead use (dir /b /r).  Will update my answer.